# JS code not running correctly, but works on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, queryselector

I'm trying to change the src of an image. I'm able to change it on console but I can't put it to work on my javascript file. The code I ran is the same as the code on my file.
Here is the excerpt of my code where it's giving me problems:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".grid-zonaAzul div img", function(event){
        if ($(event.target).attr("src") != "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraIndisponivel1.png") {
            if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionadaChapeu1.png") {
                var parentClass = $(event.target).parent().attr("class");
                var classDots = "." + parentClass.split(" ").join(".");
                console.log(classDots);
                document.querySelector(classDots + " > img");
                // document.querySelector(classDots + " > img").setAttribute("src", "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
            };
        };
    });
});
```

And on HTML there's something like this:

```
<div class="grid-zonaAzul">
    <div class="linha1a coluna1a"><img src="imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png"></div>
</div>
```

The var `parentClass` is giving me the class `linha1a coluna1a`, which is correct. But because I need it with dots, I'm running the line `var classDots = "." + parentClass.split(" ").join(".");` to turn the string to `.linha1a.coluna1a`. Also, the console.log
So basically I'm trying to get the only image inside de class `.linha1a.coluna1a`. The problem starts here, because the commented line isn't doing anything but if I run `document.querySelector(".linha1a.coluna1a > img").setAttribute("src", "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png")`, it works on console.

**Edit:** 
I'm sorry, I didn't explained somethings.
I have an image, when I click on it it changes to other image. This is working correctly. The code I posted was running when I clicked on the image again to replace the second image to the first image it was showing.
Essentially, the first click changes the src to `imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png` and the second click changes to `imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png`.

Comment: Your second `if` condition will never hit given the HTML you've shown. Did you mean `!=` instead of `==`?

Comment: If the event is raised by `<img/>` element, then is there any specific reason for  going up the DOM element tree and again selecting the same img using class selector, which you already had the reference off.. Instead, inside of second IF block src can be directly changed right? Like this : `$(event.target).attr("src","path/to/Img");`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry I missed an explanation. Please read my edit.

Comment: @Unknown The thing is, on the first click I'm using that and it's working. I have `$(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png");` and it is working but when I try do do `$(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");`, this is not working. I was going up the DOM because I was trying other alternative.

Comment: According to your code logic, **basically you are saying that if the image is "cadeiraIndisponivel1.png", then leave as it is and do nothing.** You are trying to change the image only if it is not set to "cadeiraIndisponivel1.png". _Pls correct me if am wrong_.

That is why you are able to change from "passadiço.png" to "cadeiraIndisponivel1.png" but not from "cadeiraIndisponivel1.png" to "cadeira1.png"

Comment: @Unknown Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to put only the essential code and there was somethings missing. Here's a more complete code: https://pastebin.com/XcAJjW6a

Comment: @Unknown Also, I'm was trying to put the minimum of my code and some things get wrong. I've changed the image src to the corrected one.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not setting Image to cadeiraIndisponivel1.png anywhere in the code by chance and are you sure it is entering IF or ELSE-IF block if clicked second time?

Comment: @Unknown Thank you for your help. I tried adding some `console.log`'s and saw the problem. It's funny because, when I putted the code on pastebin, I saw all those `if`'s and thought  "those `if`'s could be `else if`'s" and corrected them.

Comment: It happens all sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, it was a stupid error. I never thought the problem was on something else other the first `if`. My code was this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".grid-zonaAzul div img", function(event){
        if ($(event.target).attr("src") != "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraIndisponivel1.png") {
            if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png") {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
            }
            if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionadaChapeu1.png") {
                var parentClass = $(event.target).parent().attr("class");
                var classs = "." + parentClass.split(" ").join(".");
                console.log(classs);
                document.querySelector(classs + " > img")
                // .setAttribute("src", "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
                // $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
            }
            if ($(".w3-select").val() == "sim") {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionadaChapeu1.png");
            }
            else {
            $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem was it was entering on the second `if` and then on the third `if`. This was easily corrected by using `else if`.

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".grid-zonaAzul div img", function(event){
        if ($(event.target).attr("src") != "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraIndisponivel1.png") {
            if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png") {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
            }
            else if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionadaChapeu1.png") {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeira1.png");
            }
            else if ($(".w3-select").val() == "sim") {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionadaChapeu1.png");
            }
            else {
                $(event.target).attr("src","imagens/reservaCadeiras/cadeiraSelecionada1.png");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to change the Image1 to Image2 and from Image2 to Image3 on each click, then your condition blocks doesn't satisfy what you intend to achieve.

It should be something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".grid-zonaAzul div img", function(event){
        if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "Image1.png") {
            $(event.target).attr("src","Image2.png");
        };
         else if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "Image2.png") {
            $(event.target).attr("src","Image3.png");
        };
         else if ($(event.target).attr("src") == "Image3.png") {
            $(event.target).attr("src","Image1.png");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to change, on the first click, the Image1 to Image2 and, on the second click, the Image2 to Image1